# className and packageName of apps in emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to get className and packageName of the Apps in emulator.Iam not getting any output .please let me know the right way.

```
List<ApplicationInfo>applicationInfos=getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);

  for(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo:applicationInfos) {
                        String cn=applicationInfo.className==null?"not able to get class name":applicationInfo.className;
                       String pk=applicationInfo.packageName==null?"not able to get package name":applicationInfo.className;
                        Log.e("tag", " " + cn+"---"+pk);
                    }
```

Comment: applicationInfo.className is changed to applicationInfo.packageName

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfos=getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);

    for(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo:applicationInfos) {
        String cn=applicationInfo.className;
        String pk=applicationInfo.packageName;
        Log.i("tag", " " + cn+"---"+pk);
    }
```

Comment: use above code to get all packages in phone but for class its still showing null because of android security sandbox restrictions

Comment: i did this but i am not getting any output....n why is this android security sand box restriction....

Comment: use "tag" in android monitor to filter with info and security sandbox restrictions for app security  prevents classes from being exposed to world

Comment: how do i use tag in android monitor to see apps